# Python telebot does not send messages

Tags: python, telegram

I wrote a program that automatically sends messages in a telegram group. I use the following code:

```
import telebot


chat_id = '-123'
API_KEY = '12345'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)


text = 'Hello world!'
bot.send_message(chat_id, text=text)

exit()
```

And it works perfectly. However, whenever I run the exact same code on my old laptop, it does not work. Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

I used the command 'pip install telebot' on both laptops.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Specifically, what does "it does not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues:

1. You didn't terminate a telebot session on your new notebook while starting it on old one;
2. Actually, telebot should be installed by 'pip intall pytelegrambotapi'...

Comment: How do I terminate a telebot session?

Comment: Cntr+c or close terminal window where your Python script s running. Whatever.

Comment: Actually, i'm wrong: my advice is good if you are running bot in polling mode. So, the only first explanation remains... Check 'pip list' on your old notebook.

Answer (score 0):

On my old laptop I had the newest version (4.0.0), that one did not work.

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI==3.8.2
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

your bot is not being triggered by anything. (command, regex etc)

Do

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
   bot.send_message(message.text.id, "Hello"
#
#
#
bot.polling()
```